# AWS S3 Glacier storage restoration expiry

Tags: amazon-s3, storage, restore

When restoring an object from GLACIER, I set **"Number of days the restored copy is available"** for *X* days, after that the object copy will be removed and in order to access the file, a new restore request is needed.

I need to know when an object is restored and when it's expired and not available any more.
I use S3 Event Notifications to know when a restore is done. But how can I know when the restored copy is expired?

**Summarize my question:**

Is there any way, (using S3 Event Notifications or any other method) to know when a **restored object copy** is expired and removed?

I am trying to avoid writing for every object it's time of restoration and calculate it by number of days.

Comment: There is no S3 Event triggered when a restored object expires. I wonder whether you can use a combination of its Storage Class and (something else) to determine whether it is currently within the "Restored from Glacier" time period?

Comment: I can't seem to find any attribute that is being changed that could help me knowing if an object is currently restored or not...

Trying to think a little bit outside of the box here, but it seems there is no escape from maintaining a database that will hold every object restore time.

Any better ideas than this?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use-case? Do you frequently need to restore objects and keep them available for a period of time? If there was a way to notify when a restored copy is expired, what would you do with that information? One idea I have is to copy restored objects to a "temporary" folder that has an object lifecycle configured.

Comment: I have a database that lists the objects and different properties of them. One of the attributes is "status" ["Ready" / "Archived"]. Basically I wanted a function that changes the "status" back to "Archive" once an object expires, but the problem of course is knowing when is the right time to trigger this function.
Your idea sounds interesting, I will have to look into object lifecycles a bit more to see if this could work for me, but overall it does sound like the best option.

Comment: And regarding the frequency of restoring the objects, it shouldn't be to often, however it depends on my users and it is not something that I can really predict at the moment, however in the future it could be pretty large scales.
Anyway as I said the main reason I need to know when it has expired is to update the database with the relevant status.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable S3 server logs on the bucket and you can see a log record with operation "S3.EXPIRE.RESTORE" for the file that has been expired from the restored.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).